# Count Tags Length In Input Field On Load

Tags: angular, typescript

I got problem to count tags length in input field onload. But now it only fire [image],

I provide a code and [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tag-input-fg4l22) as your reference.

**HTML**

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
<div class="editor-tag" (click)="focusTagInput()">
    <span class="tag-item" *ngFor="let tag of tags">
          {{tag}}
          <span class="remove-tag" (click)="removeTag(tag)">×</span>
        </span>
        <input
       #tagInput type="text"
        class="input-tag"
        (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
        (onTagsinput)="eventFire($tag)"
        formControlName="tag">
      </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventFire(event);
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      tag: [undefined],
    });
  }


  eventFire(event){
   console.log(event)
  }
```

Hope you all can help me solve it

Answer (score 0):

you should use ViewChildren not ViewChild

@ViewChildren(HtmlInputElement) viewChildren: QueryList;

Comment: what the different between use ViewChildren and ViewChild?

Comment: if you have only one element in your html you can use ViewChild because it gives only the first element. If you have multi element you should use ViewChildren to get them all